# PhpStorm lost all projects & settings after power failure

Tags: phpstorm, windows-7-x64

I've lost all my project, all sftp settings, all history of files' changes. I'm very sad :(

Can i restore them? Or not?

My OS is Windows 7 (x64).

Comment: Sure. Restore from backup copy. You were doing regular backups (of important stuff, at least) right..?

Comment: Backup of what? All Windows? )
I don't do it. It's just local machine, not a server.

And I'm not sure that some files was deleted. Perhaps some rights have changed. Or the PhpStorm has some locks for read-write operation. And this logic was disrupted.

But I unfortunately do not know structure of PhpStorm , so I can only guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems PHPStorm configuration has become corrupted. Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-110311 and related tickets. This is actually Windows file system issue - it's well-known for its bad recoverability

There is no way to restore configuration, unless you use backups or share your settings using [Settings repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7566?pr=idea) plugin.

Comment: "This is actually Windows file system issue - it's well-known for its bad recoverability" Not sure this is true. I exited PHP storm to perform an SVN switch as sometimes when I switch PHP Storm indexes the files while the switch is running causing the switch to fail and need to clean-up etc.

On restarting PHP storm the settings were all lost. It appears that on Exit the files in the .idea folder were cleared by PHP storm. I restored them from a backup so I am unsure of the full nature of the change, but it looks like PHP storm caused it. SVN is set to ignore these files...

Answer (score 1):

This is an old issue & already has an accepted solution (albeit not a very helpful one), but since it's one of the first results on google when searching for similar issues I figured I'd add that I encountered exact same problem and was able to recover my settings.

After a power outage occurred while i was editing my phpstorm settings on restart, it seems othat the xml files responsible for storing custom settings were missing or in some instances "reverted" to default values.  In my case these were the live templates & keymaps located in the `~/.PhpStorm2018.2/config` directory.  I was able to restore my settings by navigating to the `jba_config` directory and copying over the settings files to their respective folders in the `config` directory.

Hopefully this helps someone that encounters a similar issue and didn't have a backup copy of their settings.