# PhpStorm lost all favorites and local branches

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

After opening PhpStorm I saw that all favorites and local branches are gone. Only possible cause that comes to mind is that I saw an error that WSL2 had to shut down with an error.

When I go to `File > Local History` it's also blank.

Can this somehow be related to WSL2 shutting down incorrectly and is there a way to restore everything?

Is there a way to store these settings online somewhere?

The closest thing I could find as a solution is this: [PhpStorm lost all projects & settings after power failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421738/phpstorm-lost-all-projects-settings-after-power-failure)

Version info.

```
PhpStorm 2021.2.2
Build #PS-212.5284.49, built on September 16, 2021
Subscription is active until November 8, 2022.
Runtime version: 11.0.12+7-b1504.28 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 6
Registry: run.processes.with.pty=TRUE
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to restore the lost data, but as far as I know, local history is stored alongside the index/cache files (see [default locations](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) for PhpStorm config files), meaning you can sync/backup it to cloud as you wish. Keep in mind that these folders might get huge over time. As for lost branches - do you mean Git? If so, those should be stored in separate `.git` folders inside the project by default.

Comment: This must mean that the project config files got corrupted (or got empty) and the IDE rejects them. Project config is normally stored in the `.idea` subfolder in your project root folder. So if the project was opened directly via WSL then it was saved there as well. I do not think you can recover them unless you have backups.

Comment: As mentioned in the first comment here (by Kristián Filo), Local History is stored at the IDE level together with indexes/caches/logs and other disposable stuff (that can be regenerated or discarded). AFAIK Local History is still quite tightly linked to the indexes so if they are corrupted it may get lost as well. **P.S.** These are the most related tickets IMO: 1) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-61385 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-15595

Comment: If your project config **has issues** and you do not have backups of your working  `PROJECT_ROOT/.idea`, you may 1) close the IDE 2) Go to PROJECT_ROOT and delete `.idea` subfolder (you may take a backup first if you wish) 3) launch the IDE again and use "Open" or alike to make a new project from those existing files (if the IDE does not auto-open the last used project for you on start). You will need to configure it from scratch though. This will not bring any of the previously configured stuff back ofc,